# Can I use regexes containing ampersands in HTML5 pattern attributes?

Tags: regex, html, escaping, pattern-matching, ampersand

I use the following email validation before submission of a form in an HTML5 webapp:

```
<input id="mail" name="mail" type="email" value="" required  placeholder="Email" 
pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?">
```

However, the ampersands in the regex seem to invalidate the HTML. Checking at http://validator.w3.org/ I get the following error message:

```
& did not start a character reference. 
(& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)
```

Is it even possible to escape ampersands in the regex without messing it up? Is the validator right in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, for example, use the hex value: `\x26`

See here: http://regex101.com/r/bF4bZ3

In other words, `[....$%&'*....]` would become `[....$%\x26'*....]`. Do the same for the rest.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion! Thank you. Still very curious though, to know whether this is how you're supposed to do it, and if it's a false alarm from the W3 validator.